# Mysql Group by second column if first column is equal?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table that looks like this

```
id | rating
1  | 1
1  | 3
1  | 1
1  | 2
2  | 3
2  | 3
2  | 1
```

etc,you get the idea.

Anyway, I want to end up with this result set

```
id | rating | num
1  | 1      | 2
1  | 3      | 1
1  | 2      | 1
2  | 3      | 2
2  | 1      | 1
```

So, what I want to do is group the rating's together **as long as the id is the same**!

I thought I could just do `group by id, rating` and just assumed it would group only if both columns were the same, but it doesn't it groups if either column is the same so I end up with

```
id | rating | num
1  | 1      | 7
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you post the query which you have tried?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like there is either a syntactical error in your query, or perhaps it is a subquery and further aggregation is going on, as the part you mentioned 'GROUP BY id, rating` is without-a-doubt the correct syntax for what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand the issue you are having. This query works for me:

```
select 
  id, rating, COUNT(rating) as num 
FROM rating 
GROUP BY id, rating 
ORDER BY id, rating ASC;
```

And, just to be thorough, here is my entire test session:

```
mysql> create table rating (id int, rating int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into rating values (1,1),(1,3),(1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(2,3),(2,1);
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select id, rating, COUNT(rating) as num FROM rating GROUP BY id, rating;
+------+--------+-----+
| id   | rating | num |
+------+--------+-----+
|    1 |      1 |   2 | 
|    1 |      2 |   1 | 
|    1 |      3 |   1 | 
|    2 |      1 |   1 | 
|    2 |      3 |   2 | 
+------+--------+-----+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks @lc. I guess it didn't cross my size threshold.

Comment: But then again, there is more value to sqlfiddle than that... duly noted. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

you could try

```
SELECT id,rating,COUNT(rating) AS num 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY id,rating
ORDER BY id ASC
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6520/4)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,rating,count(rating) from table group by id,rating
```